# Missing property on VSTS api result

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm currently trying to do some magic using the VSTS api, but something is a little  bit surprising me.

Using the method described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/definitions/get?view=vsts-rest-4.1, I made a call an receive my response.

Despite the documentation, I'm not able to read the revision counter, who is simply missing from the response. That's my goal, overwrite this counter using an homemade powershell...

Is there something I shoud know about the VSTS api, like an admin restriction or something else?

Did someone met the current issue?

Comment: You can't change the revision counter. Why do you want to?

Comment: Because I'm redefining the build number using powershell, to get a MajorVersion and MinorVersion from a json available in $(build.sourcesDirectory).As side effect, it reset the revision number, so I'm trying to handle it by myself.

Comment: The build *definition's* revision counter has nothing to do with a build's build number. I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I dont want the build def revision number, I want to get the "build process revision". You can define a build with n modifications, and execute it z time. Build number is gonna be formatted like this: $(MajorVersion).$(MinorVersion).$(z) . I want to get and update $(z) by myself.

Comment: $[ counter('name', seed) ] as the expression value seems not to be working...

Comment: I don't understand what information you want to get. Build revision? Build Definition Revision? Build Number Counter?

Comment: Take the following Build number pattern: $(Build.BuildName)_$(Build.BranchName)_$(MajorVersion).$(MinorVersion)$(Rev:.r). In my build definition, I replaced it with $(BuildName)_$(BranchName)_1.0$(Rev:.r). I also add a ps1 step how replace the 1.0 by a major and a minor version extracted from a file, followed by a step how set the new build number using ps1. the step how set the name also reset the revision counter as side effect, so I want to find it, then set it to the wright value using ps1, OR, use and increment a counter on the build definition. Is this clearest?

Comment: So the first build number is X_Y_1.0.1 and the second you want is X_Y_1.1.2?

Answer (score 0):

To get the build definition's revision counter, you should use the REST API [Get definition revisions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/definitions/get%20definition%20revisions?view=vsts-rest-4.1):

```
GET https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}/revisions?api-version=4.1
```

Then you can get all the revisions ids and counts.

Comment: That is not what I am looking for. I do not want the "definition revision", but the "build revision".